# How to set g++ 4.8 to be the default after installing?

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, c++, compiler, g++

After executing the following on Ubuntu 12.10 how do I set 4.8 to be the default C++ compiler?

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install g++-4.8
```

When I check the version it says I have 4.6 by default. I'd like to change this to 4.8.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo update-alternatives --config cc
sudo update-alternatives --config c++
```

Choose gcc 4.8 version in both cases.